# Convert .pdf to .docx on Adobe pdf services API (using Python)

Tags: python, pdf, python-docx, python-pdfreader, adobe-pdfservices

I'm trying to write a Python program converting ".pdf" files to ".docx" ones, using Adobe PDF Server API (free trial).

I've found literature enabling to transform any ".pdf" file to a ".zip" file containing ".txt" files (restoring text data) and ".excel" files (returning tabular data).

```
import logging
import os.path

from adobe.pdfservices.operation.auth.credentials import Credentials
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.exception.exceptions import ServiceApiException, ServiceUsageException, SdkException
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.pdfops.options.extractpdf.extract_pdf_options import ExtractPDFOptions
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.pdfops.options.extractpdf.extract_element_type import ExtractElementType
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.execution_context import ExecutionContext
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.io.file_ref import FileRef
from adobe.pdfservices.operation.pdfops.extract_pdf_operation import ExtractPDFOperation


logging.basicConfig(level=os.environ.get("LOGLEVEL", "INFO"))

try:
    # get base path.
    base_path =os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("C:/..link.../extractpdf/extract_txt_from_pdf.ipynb"))))

    # Initial setup, create credentials instance.
    credentials = Credentials.service_account_credentials_builder()\
        .from_file(base_path + "\\pdfservices-api-credentials.json") \
        .build()

    #Create an ExecutionContext using credentials and create a new operation instance.
    execution_context = ExecutionContext.create(credentials)
    extract_pdf_operation = ExtractPDFOperation.create_new()

    #Set operation input from a source file.
    source = FileRef.create_from_local_file(base_path + "/resources/trs_pdf_file.pdf")
    extract_pdf_operation.set_input(source)

    # Build ExtractPDF options and set them into the operation
    extract_pdf_options: ExtractPDFOptions = ExtractPDFOptions.builder() \
        .with_element_to_extract(ExtractElementType.TEXT) \
        .with_element_to_extract(ExtractElementType.TABLES) \
        .build()
    extract_pdf_operation.set_options(extract_pdf_options)

    #Execute the operation.
    result: FileRef = extract_pdf_operation.execute(execution_context)

    # Save the result to the specified location.
    result.save_as(base_path + "/output/Extract_TextTableau_From_trs_pdf_file.zip")
except (ServiceApiException, ServiceUsageException, SdkException):
    logging.exception("Exception encountered while executing operation")
```

But I can't yet get the conversion done to a ".docx" file, event after changing the name of the extracted file to `name.docx`

I went to read the litterature of `adobe.pdfservices.operation.pdfops.options.extractpdf.extract_pdf_options.ExtractPDFOptions()` but didn't found ways to tune the extraction and change it from ".zip" to ".docx". What things can I try next?

Comment: Instead of posting an answer to add information, please [edit] your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, right now the Python SDK is only supporting the Extract portion of our PDF services. You could use the services via the REST APIs (https://documentcloud.adobe.com/document-services/index.html#how-to-get-started-) as an alternative.